# accesoryView out of the screen on iPad

Tags: ipad, uitableview

We have the same code for a UITableView on iPhone and on IPad.

For every row we show an accesory view with an specific icon.

In iphone works perfectly, but in iPad ... for some reason the accessory doesn't appears, and when you select one of the rows, you could see them in the transition ... Is like them are out of the screen.

Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Ivan

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I found a mistake in the tableview.frame on viewDidLoad ...

:S